# How to see and go to local branches in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I have just created a brand-new git repository:

```
git init
```

By executing

```
git status
```

I have determined that I am in the master branch. The first line of the output was:

```
On branch master
```

As a first step I wanted to create a branch and go in there. I have learned that one can do these two steps just by one command:

```
git checkout -b aaa
```

I this way I have created a branch called "aaa" and went there. I could confirm it with "git status" (it tells me "On branch aaa"). Now I want to go back to the "master" branch. So, I execute:

```
git checkout master
```

As a result I get:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

So, how do I go to another (existing) branch in git? Moreover, I do not even know what branches exist. How can I see a list of existing branches?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` show you?

Comment: It shows nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had no commit in `master` branch so, `master` does not exist actually.

Create & checkout local `master` branch:

```
$ git checkout -b master
```

You can see branch list(s):

```
$ git branch       # see local branch(es)
$ git branch -r    # see remote branch(es)
$ git branch -a    # see all local & remote branch(es)
```

Do changes, `git add -A`, `git commit -m 'message'`. So, now this commit actually point to the `master` branch.

**N.B.** By `git init` command default branch is `master` (it's not real branch, just default git convention). Then without doing any commit you checked out to `aaa` branch. So, `master` is vanished cause no branch exists without any commit history.

Comment: But "master" branch existed. Then I have created and switched to branch "aaa". You mean that master branch disappeared because of that? Anyway, I have executed "git checkout -b master" and, as a result of it, I am in the master branch but "git branch" does not show anything. So I guess that the branch "aaa" now has disappeared. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, because your `master` or `aaa` has no commit actually. Do a commit then that branch will have existed.

Comment: @Roman You don't have any commits yet, so that complicates things.  Sajib's answer looks basically right to me.

Comment: This is not intuitive. It is like I create a folder on my file system and my operation system decided to remove an empty folder as soon as I leave it (because it is empty).

Comment: a branch in git has nothing to do with file system. A branch is just a set of commits and a HEAD pointer, pointing to some commit. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

Comment: @sashok_bg, I know that a git-branch is not a folder in a file system. But still it is something that you can "create", "go into", "remove". It also "contains" something. It is strange that the system deletes these objects (branches) without your explicit command for that.

Comment: @Roman I agree on that one, it seems a bit counter intuitive at first

Answer (score 0):

`git branch` will show you your local branches with a `*` to show your active one

`git branch --all` includes upstream tracking branches

It's also useful to add the `-vv` very verbose switch to get more information too

Related to Sajib's answer, a branch in git is just a reference to the leaf commit of a chain of commits. This can be shown by `git show-ref`

e.g.

```
$ git show-ref
134d0c9e480ed26a4f8867215aa9e36ac8563d93 refs/heads/master
134d0c9e480ed26a4f8867215aa9e36ac8563d93 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
134d0c9e480ed26a4f8867215aa9e36ac8563d93 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

In this case HEAD, origin/master and master all refer to the same commit in my local repository.

As Sajib suggests, with out a commit there can be no reference and so no actual branch in the repository

If you do a first commit after running `git checkout -b aaa` then the only concrete branch in your repository will be the one `aaa` you could then rename it to master with `git branch -m master` where `-m` is move

Comment: All the three commands that you have suggested produce no output at all.

Comment: Added some info about references to my answer

Answer (score 0):

To answer why your branch is not seen after you moved from it:

In git a branch is just a set commits and a pointer that points to where your branch HEAD is. Since your initial branch "master" has no commits, the HEAD points to void and it appears that git interprets only pointers that point to something.

I encourage you to read the documentation that explains the internals of git. This will help you understand what happens behind the scenes and will help you easily answer your own questions:

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

> A branch in Git is simply a lightweight movable pointer to one of these commits. The default branch name in Git is master. As you initially make commits, you’re given a master branch that points to the last commit you made. Every time you commit, it moves forward automatically.
>
> What happens if you create a new branch? Well, doing so creates a new
>   pointer for you to move around. Let’s say you create a new branch
>   called testing. You do this with the git branch command:

P.S Git provides an abstraction over the file system so you cannot really look at branches as they were folders or files.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. A concept of branches is probably the first concept that a git-beginner will face. It is pity that even for the first concept to understand you need to understand such stuff as "head", "pointer" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question's and comment's on it, You are saying you already had **Master** branch but somehow it's not showing now when you hit 
**git branch**
please hit **git fetch** for fetching remote branches.

for further reference and more learning on git you can play this fun loving game https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 :)